# How do I convert oracle regexp_substr to PostgreSQL using HQL

Tags: java, postgresql, oracle, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to convert below OracleDB HQL where clause  to PosgreSQL.
HQL is using PosgreSQL dialect.

Both queries work on databases directly with no issues.

OracleDB:

```
...
where  
( LPAD(regexp_substr(someTable.someColumn, '\d+', 1,1), 3, ' ') = ' 40' 
AND LPAD(regexp_substr(someTable.someColumn, '\d+', 1,2), 3, ' ') = ' 20');
```

---

PosgreSQL:

```
...
where
( LPAD(( SELECT array_to_string(a, '') from regexp_matches(someTable.someColumn, '\d+', 'g') as a limit 1 offset 0), 3, ' ') = ' 40' 
AND LPAD(( SELECT array_to_string(a, '') from regexp_matches(someTable.someColumn, '\d+', 'g') as a limit 1 offset 1), 3, ' ') = ' 20' );
```

After the change in the code, I keep getting below hql exception on runtime:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
unexpected token: regexp_matches near line 1
```

I've also registered below function custom dialect class but it didn't work as well:

```
public class CustomPostgresqlDialect extends PostgreSQL82Dialect  {

    public CustomPostgresqlDialect() {
    super();
    registerFunction( "regexp_matches", new StandardSQLFunction( "regexp_matches", StandardBasicTypes.STRING ) );
    }   
}
```

And if I keep using original **regexp_substr** version, there is PostgreSQL exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function regexp_substr(character varying, unknown, integer, integer) does not exist
```

Please suggest if there is a way to convert such query so that HQL won't fail to parse it.
Also I can't switch to native query creation since there is huge part which HQL generates.

Many thanks

Comment: I think your Postgres solution is way too complicated. What exactly are you trying to achieve there? I _think_ a `regexp_split_to_array()`  might make that a lot simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you want to check multiple matches from the same regex. In Postgres the way to do that would be with the `g` flag on the regex so that it returns you all the matches, not just the first.

I think that instead of this:

```
LPAD(( SELECT array_to_string(a, '') from regexp_matches(someTable.someColumn, '\d+', 'g') as a limit 1 offset 1)
```

you can do this

```
LPAD(regexp_matches(someTable.someColumn, '\d+', 'g')[1])
```

With the first approach you have to change the index you pass to the HQL function. The other problem is the StandardSQLFunction class is inappropriate for this, as your implementation is too custom. You have to implement your own renderer.

```
public class PgRegexMatcher implements SQLFunction {

    public boolean hasArguments() { return true; }
    public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() { return true; }
    public Type getReturnType(Type firstArgumentType, Mapping mapping) throws QueryException {
        return StandardBasicTypes.STRING;
    }

    public String render(Type firstArgumentType, List arguments, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws QueryException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
        sb.append("regexp_matches(")
          .append(arguments.get(0))
          .append(", '\d+', 'g')[")
          .append(arguments.get(1))
          .append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Now in HQL you would use it as `regexp_func(sometable.column1, x)` (with `regexp_func` being whatever name you registered it as) and it will generate `regexp_matches(sometable.column1, '\d+', 'g')[x]` in your Postgresql dialect, and you seem to already have the one for your Oracle dialect figured out.

Because the array indexes here start at 1 you can do this without adjusting the values between the dialects.

Comment: Thank yo so much. So render part was missing for me.
btw I had to use full query 
SELECT array_to_string(a, '') from regexp_matches(someTable.someColumn, '\d+', 'g')


Instead of suggested:
regexp_matches(someTable.someColumn, '\d+', 'g')[1]

As in pgAdmin it did fail with syntax error at or near "["

Comment: Ah, it seems I misunderstood what `regexp_matches` returns. It returns rows of array elements, where the `1` index of each array is the full mach, and subsequent indexes correspond to capturing groups, if any. Glad the rest of my answer helped.